# Is there an element is best for "Drag and drop" web applications?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building my own "Drag and Drop" web application.

I'm loading data from MySQL and create a HTML element with it.
So I have ID, length, height and so on.

Later I'm going to drag these "blocks" into a square.

Now, which HTML element is best for this?
`<div>`, `<canvas>`, `<img>`?

An example will be with a `<div>`:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height:20px; background-color: grey;"></div>
```

Which element is best suited for being dragged and dropped?
I'm going to save positions for dragged elements, for loading it later..

Specifically, is there a technical reason to prefer one element over any other?

Comment: Unfortunately, this website is not for suggestions

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a best suited element for this. Generally I'll use divs, but it depends on what you want to do. If you wanna do it the HTML5 way, simply add a `draggable="true"` attribute. If you're open to using libraries, jQuery UI has a very good drag and drop implementation.

Comment: And how do you store the new position? Are you moving divs into divs? How do you get position in a div?

Comment: You can use `dragstart`, `dragover`, and `drop` events in conjunction with the `draggable` element. The callbacks given to these listeners will have an event object as a first parameter which store positions you can use.